# unable to change state value in usestate hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

how i can change an object value inside a state

```
const [data, setData] = useState({value: 10})
```

I want to decrease the value every time an user clicks a button and it renders in webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value from passing a callback function to setter and return the new value.

```
function onClick(){
setData(curr => ({...curr,value: curr.value - 1}))
}
```

For single value you can directly set the number instead of an object.

```
const [data, setData] = useState(10)

 function onClick(){
    setData(curr => curr - 1)
 }
```

Comment: While that will work properly its always better to destructure your object in case there are other values in the object. Like this: `function onClick(){
setData(curr => ({...curr, value: curr.value - 1})
}` (Also its curr.value not just curr in the first function)

Comment: Yes I noticed that `data` was having only single property , so that's why i didn't destructure it. Updated it now.